# Having trouble getting rollbar.js to build in a node/webpack-based project

Tags: node.js, webpack, rollbar

We're hoping to use Rollbar.js in our node/webpack/babel/ES6/React-based project. It's not 100% clear what the right NPM package is to use, but it appears to be this one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollbar

From there, the instructions are pretty straightforward: add a reference to `package.json`, install, and off you go. So here's the reference in `package.json`:

`"rollbar": "0.6.2",`

Running `npm install` appears to work just fine, but then when I run `npm start`, I get this error in the console:

```
ERROR in ./~/rollbar/lib/parser.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in [myProjectRoot]node_modules/rollbar/lib
 @ ./~/rollbar/lib/parser.js 7:9-22

ERROR in ./~/rollbar/package.json
Module parse failed: [myProjectRoot]node_modules/rollbar/package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:9)
    at Parser.pp.raise ([myProjectRoot]node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:923:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected ([myProjectRoot]node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1490:8)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon ([myProjectRoot]node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1469:73)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpressionStatement ([myProjectRoot]node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1994:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement ([myProjectRoot]node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1772:188)
    at Parser.pp.parseBlock ([myProjectRoot]node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2009:21)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement ([myProjectRoot]node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1753:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel ([myProjectRoot]node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1666:21)
    at Parser.parse ([myProjectRoot]node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1632:17)
    at Object.parse ([myProjectRoot]node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:885:44)
 @ ./~/rollbar/lib/notifier.js 14:18-44
```

I can't make any sense out of this. It appears to suggest that my webpack project cannot parse Rollbar's `package.json` file, but that doesn't seem possible, given that my webpack project has countless other NPM packages, each with their own `package.json` file.

Anybody run into this issue?

UPDATE:

In case it's relevant, here's our complete `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const glob = require('glob');

const modulesDirectories = glob.sync('src/**');
const assetsDirectories = glob.sync('assets/**');
Array.prototype.push.apply(
    modulesDirectories,
    assetsDirectories
);
modulesDirectories.push('assets');
modulesDirectories.push('/');
modulesDirectories.push('node_modules');


const modulesDirectoriesWithoutFiles = modulesDirectories.filter(directory => {
    if (directory.slice(-4, -3) === '.' || directory.slice(-3, -2) === '.') {
        return false;
    }
        return true;
});


module.exports = {
  cache: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'eventsource-polyfill',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
            {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          loader: 'babel',
          query: {
              // https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options
              cacheDirectory: true
          },
          include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
        { test: /\.woff|.ttf|.eot|.woff2$/, loader: `file-loader` },
        { test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/, loader: `url-loader?limit=8192` },
        ]
    },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        FIREBASE_CONFIG: JSON.stringify({
                apiKey: [ourApiKey],
                authDomain: [ourDomain],
                databaseURL: [ourUrl],
                storageBucket: [ourBucket],
              })   
    })

  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    root: __dirname,
    modulesDirectories: modulesDirectoriesWithoutFiles,
  } 
};
```

SECOND UPDATE:

Still can't get things to build, but I've got a little more information. If I remove the Rollbar import from my code, then the console errors go away. I've tried importing Rollbar in two ways, as follows:

`import rollbar from "rollbar";`
`var Rollbar = require('rollbar');`

Both attempts produce the same error. If I add `node: {fs: "empty"}` to my `webpack.config.js` file, then the 'fs' error disappears, but the "appropriate loader" error remains.

Comment: Have you tried opening an issue with the Rollbar developer  (https://github.com/rollbar/node_rollbar/issues)?

Comment: Already done. There was a similar issue already that was closed a few months back. Similar enough that it made sense for me to add to it rather than open a new issue, but different enough that I wasn't able to get my issue resolved (the original poster didn't really follow up, so the issue just got closed). However, the issues tracker for that Github repo doesn't appear to be all that active, so I wanted to throw this question out here as well.

Comment: The thing is, if you have a problem *within* a module you use, you either get the original developer to fix and republish, or you'd have to fix it yourself. And for proper use, you'd want to fork the module, fix it, and either submit a PR to the original, or publish your own module - both of which mean a lot of work.

Comment: Also, from previous such issues, try adding `node: {fs: 'empty'}` to your webpack config file. Let me know if it works.

Comment: i just installed rollbar and published a message, it's working fine. No, issues with the module. Kindly share your implementation code.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy: `node: {fs: "empty"}` had no effect. @nivesh: The code I can share here is just our webpack.config.js file, since the project won't build if I include Rollbar (which means how Rollbar actually gets invoked within the project itself is irrelevant, I'd think). i've updated the original post to include our webpack.config.js file

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same issue. I fixed it by:

1. Installing `fs` using `npm install --save fs`. Alternatively, you can add `node: {fs: "empty"}` to your webpack config, as suggested in comments. Either of these takes care of the `fs` import in rollbar/lib/parser.js.
2. Installing a [json loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader), then adding this loader to your webpack config under modules -> loaders. This informs webpack that it should use the json loader when loading JSON files. Webpack should then be able to import `package.json` in rollbar/lib/notifier.js.

   > ```
   > module: {
   >     loaders: [
   >         {
   >             test: /\.json$/,
   >             loader: "json"
   >         },
   >         ...
   >     ],
   >     ...
   > }
   > ```